# How do you test capsules that access user profile?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am interested in making a capsule that will pull information like the user's email and address from their profile. According to [this](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.self), it seems like this is entirely possible, however is there a way to create a user profile in the simulator and test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self.GetImaginarySelf` method might be useful in this scenario. This is not documented but appears to return a Self object that you can work with.

[image]

and this is how it looks 
[image]

```
action (ReturnMySelf) {
  type(Constructor)
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)
  collect {
    computed-input (mySelf) {
      type (self.Self)
      compute {
        intent {
          goal: self.GetImaginarySelf
        }
      }
    }
  }
  output (self.Self)
}
```

Javascript code

```
module.exports.function = function returnMySelf (mySelf) {
  return mySelf
}
```

If those values do not work for you, you can construct the JSON representation of a Self object (with the desired values) and pass it back from `returnMySelf.js`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Bixby IDE cannot test viv.self or viv.contact.

However, you can do on-device testing on any Bixby enable phone, such as S9 by following these steps.

1. Develop your capsule in the IDE.
2. Do [private submission](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/deploying.can-submission) of that capsule.
3. Enable [on-device testing](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/testing.on-device) and load capsule using revision ID.

On-device testing is not as straight forward as compile and run in the IDE, but a necessary step in every capsule development.
Have fun with Bixby!